# Django doesn't recognize my 'certificate.pem' file

Tags: python, django, certificate, apple-push-notifications

I'm developing the 'APNS push' function.

My Push class is below :

```
from apns import APNs, Frame, Payload
class Push:
def sendMessage(self,msg):
    # Send a notification
    apns = APNs(use_sandbox=True, cert_file='mypem.pem')
    token_hex = 'UUIDfromiOSDevice'
    payload = Payload(alert="Hello World!", sound="default", badge=1)
    apns.gateway_server.send_notification(token_hex, payload)
```

mypem.pem and push.py having class Push belong in the same app (~/mypem.pem, ~/push.py)

When def 'sendMessage' is called by DjangoRestFramework,

> "self._context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile) IOError: [Errno 2]
>   No such file or directory"

These error messages above are showing.

Is there anything I'm missing now?

Comment: Does it work when you specify an absolute path?

Comment: @AntoinePinsard I solved this by BASE_DIR_PATH

Comment: @AntoinePinsard Then I got an error "SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib". Do you know what this means?

Comment: Did you ever sort this out?

Comment: @AndrewBurnett Yes, Is there anything I didn't do? I don't know what I have to do when there's no answer.

Comment: @LKM You can provide your own answer for those users who come across the post in the future.

Comment: @AndrewBurnett A-HA! Thank you, It was solved by your answer at the top with specifying an absolute path. Actually, not mine

Answer (score 0):

It was solved with specifying 'BASE_DIR_PATH' and the next error I got after specifying 'BASE_DIR_PATH' was caused by the pem file created wrongly.